# Incomplete beta function and implicit function

Tags: real-analysis, beta-function

Say $\,y\,$ is implicitly given by
$$
I_y(\alpha+1,\beta) = \frac{1}{B(\alpha+1,\beta)}\int_0^y t^{\alpha}(1-t)^{\beta-1}dt=k\,.
$$
where $\,0<k<1\,$ is a constant.
Using Matlab for numerical experiments, I found that $\,I_y(\alpha,\beta)\,$ is decreasing in $\alpha$, can we prove it analytically?

Comment: The answer to your question will be in differentiating $I$ with respect to $\alpha$. That will be can of worms, on many levels, not the least of which will be the digamma functions that accrue with the derivative of $B$. Looking at the integral alone, i.e., the incomplete beta function, I read that it's quite dull. When two of the variables are held constant, the function decreases monotonically with $\alpha$ and with $\beta$ and increases monotonically with $y$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am not sure that $I_y(\alpha,\beta)$ is decreasing in $\alpha$ since $y$ is also affected by $\alpha$. Actually, $y$ decreases monotonically with $\alpha$.